# Unit test for SpringBoot Service PUT method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I'm writing Unit tests for my SpringBoot application and I'm completely lost in the PUT method. I'm getting `Expecting code to raise a throwable` but I guess the complete test is wrong.

Here's my code:

**the PUT method in the Service**

```
public void updateCar(String id, String carModel, Integer HP, Integer year, String designer) {
    Garage garage = garageRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                    "A car with the id " + id + " is not in our Garage."));
    if(carModel != null && carModel.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getCarModel(), carModel)) {
        garage.setCarModel(carModel);
    }
    if(HP != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getHP(), HP)) {
        garage.setHP(HP);
    }
    if(year != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getYear(), year)) {
        garage.setYear(year);
    }
    if(designer != null && designer.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getDesigner(), designer)) {
        garage.setDesigner(designer);
    }
    garageRepository.save(garage);
}
```

**My Repository:**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface GarageRepository extends MongoRepository<Garage, String> {

Optional<Garage> findByCarModel(String carModel); }
```

**And here's a test:**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Update Car Test")
void testUpdateCar() {

String id = "630ca281f12905d5f5249f08";
String carModel = "Shelby Cobra";
int HP = 485;
int year = 1964;
String designer = "Carroll Shelby";

Garage testGarage = new Garage();
testGarage.setId(id);

given(garageRepository.findById(testGarage.getId()))
        .willReturn(Optional.of(testGarage));
assertThatThrownBy(() -> garageService.updateCar(id,carModel,HP,year,designer))
        .isInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
        .hasMessageContaining("A car with the id " + id + " is not in our Garage.");
verify(garageRepository.findById(id).get().getId());
}
```

Other tests are fine (Create, Read, and Delete), but just this one confuses the hell out of me. I don't think the Controller is necessary, so I skipped adding it.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up your test so that `findById` is returning an `Optional` containing `testGarage`.  That is, something is actually being found.

The `updateCar` method only throws the `IllegalStateException` if `findById` returns an empty `Optional` - in other words, there's no object in the repository matching the search criterion.

So in this case, the exception is never thrown, and that's what makes the test fail.

Comment: Ok, I get that part now. But is the test pointed in the right direction? Am I doing it right?

Comment: It's hard to say.  I would have expected you to have more than one test method for `updateCar`.  Definitely one where `findById` returns empty, and one where it returns an object.  Probably also a case where `carModel`, `HP`, `year` and `designer` come back as null, and a case where they're all populated.  You'll find you need to use better names for your test methods than just `testUpdateCar`.  Use names that reflect the scenario that you're testing, and what you expect to happen.  For example `updateCar_ThrowsException_WhenNoMatchingCar` and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I'm still stuck with the same problem. Do you have an idea what the test should look like to pass, because I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: Well, if you're trying to test the case where the exception is thrown, then instead of using `testGarage`, you'll need something like `given(garageRepository.findById(id)).willReturn(Optional.empty());`